# Flink SQL with JDBC - how to identify the updated rows

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-jdbc

I am new to Flink. We are building a web interface where users could submit Flink SQL queries to query Kafka topics.

We are using recently released JDBC driver for this in the backend.

However, whenever we submit aggregate queries, result set continously retunrs the updated rows without any other indicators. We want to update the values of previsouly emitted rows.

For example there's a group by query with count. It needs to show only the grouped column and the updated value continously. With JDBC result set we do get the updates value, but there's no way to identify previous column  which this update is for.

This fucntionality is already there in Flink sql client that comes bundled with Flink binary. However we want this functioanlity on web.

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some code examples it will be easier to understand/reproduce your case